# Ebean filter list in @OneToMany relation

Tags: java, filter, one-to-many, ebean, many-to-one

I have problem with filtering lists in @OneToMany realations by multiple choices. Exactly I have two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Table1 extends Model {

@OneToMany
public List<Table2> table2;

}


   @Entity
   public class Table2 extends Model {

   @ManyToOne
   public Table1 table1;

   public String someValue;

   }
```

So, I want to fetch all Objects of Table1 where in its List of Table2, some value has two exact values. For example:

Find all Table1 where in table2, someValue = 1 and someValue =2

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Table1> filteredTable = Table1.find
    .fetch("Table2")
    .where()
    .eq("t1.someValue","1")
    .findList();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.